# Finding the best data source query strategy for a ml model. Maximizing quality, minimizing cost

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, ensemble-modeling

It is too expensive to query all data sources for each claim, so it is necessary to define a sourcing strategy to maximize the model quality score and minimize the cost of prediction (expressed in money terms) over the entire data distribution.

I have several machine learning models that train on different data from different sources, and on all combinations of them. For example, if there are only 2 sources a and b, then there will be 4 models: no source, only a, only b, a and b together.

Each source has a cost per 1 application.
Model predictions are well calibrated, so the final predictions for the entire dataset can be considered as predictions of one meta model.

The problem is that when predicting, we do not know in advance what this or that source will answer. If there is no data (no_hit), then its cost is 0, and the gain in model quality is 0 (for example, roc_auc). Otherwise, we need to pay for it (hit). It is also possible to determine other possible scenarios. For example, the prediction of the model by source is equal to 0.01 or 0.99 - it is obvious that there is no need to request other data (no_hit,score<0.01,score>=0.01 and score<0.99, score>=0.99)

Example. There are 2 sources a and b. Their cost is 3 and 2. I know the statistical distribution of the scenarios on the training data. Let's say there are 100 samples, 10 have only a source, 20 have only b source, 30 have both sources, 40 have none of them.

One possible strategy
Request source a. If a is a hit, then predict the target by the model at source a. If a is not a hit, then request source b.
If b hit, then predict target on sources a and b. If b no hit , then predict by the model on the available data (on source a).

Thus, 10 samples will be predicted only by the model on a, 30 will be predicted by the ensemble model a and b, for the rest there will be no sources and rates. The total cost is 3*10+30*(3+2)=180. The final quality of the meta model is a metric on the combined score (10 only for a, 30 for a and b, the rest are dummy prediction).

That is, the strategy can be represented as a tree. But with 2 kinds of sheets. 1 view - source (a, b, stop and predict with available data) 2 view - script (hit, no hit). And the strategies are all possible subtrees, where all the last leaves at the end have the option to stop and predict with the available data). This should include all scenarios if a source has been selected (hit and no hit ).
Schematically, all possible options and the strategy described above in the figure:
[image: all_variants]

It is not possible to roughly sort through all possible strategies if there are many data sources (for example, 10).

Please advise how this task can be optimized. Maybe there is a ready-made solution, or there is a mathematical description and algorithms for this problem, or you have experience in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, models that answers scenarios are not 100% reliable, is it your case?

In that case, one good solution is to have a training data set, in which you know the best values the model has to reach.

In your decision tree, you set random weights that you can modify through the training process (thousands of iterations), until reaching optimal values that would reach the maximum score possible.

An even better option is to use a random forest classification because all scenarios would be explored thoroughly, even the ones that you couldn't have prepared.

However, exploring many scenarios could require a lot of processing: in this case, it is possible to start with a small set of data and models to see if this solution works well.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/prashant111/random-forest-classifier-tutorial/notebook

Comment: Nicoloas, are you proposing using an RF to fit a model on the data or an RF to decide what models to query? I assume the latter but its a little vague to me.

Comment: Ideally both but I don't know your models and datasets to decide if models are more or less meaningful than datasets to apply RF. If the training time is short, you can explore many scenarios quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you propose to turn to the multiclass model selection problem, where there will be as many classes as there are model options, and predict the best model for a new sample? But how to take into account the cost of calling sources.

Comment: And the second problem. Suppose the meta model decided that this sample should be predicted by the model for sources a and e. We ask for e , it is no_hit. How to be then? I need to choose the optimal strategy that will choose in real time how many sources to query and in what sequence, depending on what the hit / no hit will be on the new data. I do not really understand how to solve this problem using rf, although I understand how it works.

Comment: About RF, you could apply thousands of random scenarios with different models and data sets and then apply a RF classification (with scores). As a result, you would have a model that could propose the best solution (or at least a relatively good one) for any data in input. But you need all the possible data sets and models to make it work.: if there is 100% new data as input, you could apply a correlation algorithm to see if it is close enough to an existing one. In all cases, you have to find a way to process new data with old ones. I would need more info about the data to help you more.

Comment: @Andrew does everything answer your question? If not, please let me know.

Comment: Nicolas, when it comes to the meta model? Why not enunciate and determine the optimal path for every conceivable combination of hit and fail? IF A & ~B & D, THEN XYZ.  etc. It seems to me that you could just write down all possible solutions since you have cost, probability and reward. It should just be an optimization problme.

Comment: Indeed @user70889, but Andrew may not have all results from all combinations: I don't know if it is possible to have them easily.

Comment: Could we just sample them all exactly once. We pay a large fixed cost, but over time, we'll always make an optimal decision. There is certainly a break even point and we don't know what it is. But if this is a frequent/long run thing, it is probably better in the long run.

Comment: Nicolas, I don't really understand your solution. How do I write a classification problem with rf ? I have all models, on all sources and their intersections. I have info about hit /no_hit old samples.

Comment: @user70889, the problem is that I can only calculate the quality of the roc_auc ranking on the entire dataset, and not calculate the gain and cost for a separate intersection of hits.

Comment: @user70889. If we set the optimization problem as a black box problem, where we will have 1024 variables for 10 sources (10 ^ 2 hit / no_hit combinations). And each variable can take n_i values, where n_i is the number of possible models for a given hit intersection. For example 3 sources. a & ~b & c models can be a,a+c,empty,c. That is, n_i = 4. For 10 sources, there will be much more. And already minimize the function something like the price / (quality of the meta model). But such a task is too expensive to calculate in my case.

Comment: I'm sorry but at this point I just can't grasp what exactly you are doing. Best of luck solving this!

Comment: @user70889 , If there is an opportunity to somehow contact (for example, by email), I could describe in detail and with illustrations what I propose, it is not very convenient to describe in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am too busy currently in life to take on this kind of work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that using a standard ML model could be done here. But I think home brewing your own optimization function/problem would be best here. You can assign costs, probabilities and gains. Ask the computer to maximize this function. Even if you have 10 variables, this should be doable; 1024 possible combinations by my math.

Why? Because we can see the whole state space and have a reasonable estimate of it. We can know if you query, a and b and get two hits, what the likely returns are of hitting any other letter and if its worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, you just want to offer to choose the best model in terms of quality / price and then always apply it. However, this is not what I need. Indeed, depending on the hit / no hit of the source, the subsequent steps will also change. All sources can be used at the same time, but for different parts of the dataset.

Comment: And the previous called sources matter. If we have already chosen source a, then all subsequent models should include it, otherwise why did we pay for it.